# CSS: box-sizing inherit

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using cssmaterialize and they have a "pop up" type thing that they call a modal. When I use this in page pop up, if it gets bigger then a certain size it adds a scroll bar which I do not want:

[image]

I do not want the scroll bar because as you can see in the image, there is still room for the pop up to extend down a little and not need a pop up.

I decided to use chromes inspect element feature to look into the css and try and fix this small issue. I could not find anything that dealt with its height. The only thing I can think it related to it is where it says `box-size inherit`

[image]

If anyone wants to see the CSS, here is a link to the library I am using:

http://materializecss.com/

Comment: Thanks for the vote down... explanation would be nice.

Comment: You might want to change the height for `.modal` selector. Adding `overflow:hidden;` to the selector might will get rid of the scrollbar but hide the content that doesn't fit.

Comment: See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: how about adding simple hack on the css `.modal { max-height: inherit !important; }` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through the CSS, I found where the modal height is taken care of:

```
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  padding: 0;
  max-height: 80%;
  width: 55%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border-radius: 2px;
  will-change: top, opacity; }
  @media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {
    .modal {
      width: 80%; } }
  .modal h1, .modal h2, .modal h3, .modal h4 {
    margin-top: 0; }
  .modal .modal-content {
    padding: 24px; }
  .modal .modal-close {
    cursor: pointer; }
  .modal .modal-footer {
    border-radius: 0 0 2px 2px;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    padding: 4px 6px;
    height: 56px;
    width: 100%; }
    .modal .modal-footer .btn, .modal .modal-footer .btn-large, .modal .modal-footer .btn-flat {
      float: right;
      margin: 6px 0; }
```

max-height was at 70% I changed it to 80% and it fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the scrollbar with overflow:hidden;

Comment: But the box still will hide the bottom part and need to be "scrolled" by the user. I want to extend the box a little, so nothing is clipped at all.

Comment: Can you edit the height to have a min-height:300px; or something like that? I  think the reason you're question got down votes I think is because people didnt understand what you're asking for.

Comment: People are harsh on stack...Brooke tried to help, not what I was looking for but he at least tried. Does not mean everyone needs to down vote....

Comment: Not exactly sure which theme you're using, can also trying changing box-sizing: to border-box, or content-box.